# C display: none перестает работать скрипт

Tags: javascript, css

Всем привет, есть скрипт который находит место человека в таблице рейтинга

```
    function ura(){
    var num_reyt = 0;
    var score = $('.xdget-trainingAchievements .badge').html().split(' ')[0];
    var ar = document.querySelectorAll(".all_rating tbody td:nth-child(2)");
    var spisok = [];
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        content = ar[i].innerText
        spisok.push(content);
    }
    
    console.log(spisok)
    for (var m = 0; m < spisok.length; m++) {
        if (spisok[m] == score) {
            num_reyt = m + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(num_reyt);
    $(".scn").text(num_reyt);
```

Скрипт работает, но когда я для элемента .all_rating прописываю display: none; перестает работать. Так вот как мне скрыть элемент, но чтобы скрипт работал. opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; не подходят, и за того что остается много незаполненного места

Comment: Вам нужно перестать работать c DOM — работать с данными намного приятнее. Каким образом заполняется `all_rating` ? Ну и как минимум что я могу предложить если Вы не захотите работать с данными, поработать со стилями размера при `opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;` чтобы они Вам подошли.

Comment: Через load() я загружаю данные в all_rating с другой страницы. Про opacity, visibility писал, они не подходят, так как остается после них большое количество пространства снизу. И что вы подразумеваете под "работать с данными"?

Comment: если вы отрегулируете высоту, то не будет ничего оставаться, `overflow: hidden` загрузили данные через load() с ними и работайте, они у Вас в массиве же?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло